# How to debug curl on IIS?

Tags: php, iis, curl

How to inspect CURL requests?

My PHP scripts are hosted on IIS and I want to find some debugging tool for CURL.
Could you suggest something in fiddler-style?

(Or maybe there is a way to use fiddler itself, I failed to do so because if I make my CURL to tunnel through proxy 127.0.0.1 it makes CONNECT requests instead of GET)

Comment: Ethereal is now Wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: you can probably run the scripts with PHP command line to avoid issues that IIS might cause.

Comment: What environment are you trying to debug from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) is not working for HTTPS but for HTTP only.

Can you change your curl script to use HTTP ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl -v` for verbose mode.

From `man curl`

```
-v/--verbose
      Makes  the  fetching  more verbose/talkative. Mostly useful for debugging. A line starting
      with '>' means "header data" sent by curl, '<' means "header data" received by  curl  that
      is  hidden in normal cases, and a line starting with '*' means additional info provided by
      curl.

      Note that if you only want HTTP headers in the output, -i/--include might  be  the  option
      you're looking for.

      If  you think this option still doesn't give you enough details, consider using --trace or
      --trace-ascii instead.

      This option overrides previous uses of --trace-ascii or --trace.
```