# HOWTO observe  network traffic for curl debugging

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a curl call that also pass an image file along.
Obviously it's not working for me. However, I've got a test working that just use straight up html form.

How can I debug / print out the raw data that is being passed from curl?
Trying to compare the call with the form version to see what is different.

I've tried these:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
```

But those seems to just return the response as opposed the raw request. (it's through a 3rd party so I have no access to the end point)

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: How are you adding the image to the curl request?

Answer (score 1):

`curl` the command line client has a `--trace-ascii` option for that. But that feature is not exposed in the PHP interface.

The `_VERBOSE` output might however still contain some information (if it's really a server error). You must redirect it into a separate file however before:

```
$fp = fopen("curl.log", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
```

Failing that, I'm afraid the best option is to peek at the network traffic (using a separate tool, ad-hoc proxy maybe).

Comment: Pom, better then mine ( => deleted), but my votes are cast for the day :)

Answer (score 1):

This one helped me debug it. Doesn't print the entire thing, but did print the header which was super helpful.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

see previous answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236505/how-to-debug-curl-on-iis) for similar question.

Use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to observe network traffic and add a filter 'ip.addr == x.x.x.x' with the IP of the target website.